# Update 1st column based on string present in 2nd column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

### I want to update price 2 times if there is "buy 1 get 1 50%" and 3 times if "buy 1 get 1 40%"

1. Price|  Special_Offer
2. 330  | BUY 1 GET 1 50%
3. 810  | BUY 1 GET 1, 40%
4. 210  |BUY 1,GET 1 at 50%

### Below is my code, but it is not working

```
DF["Price"]=np.where(DF["Special Offer"].str.contains(r"(BUY 1)(GET1)(50%)",case=False,regex=True),DF["Price]*2,DF["Price])
```

Comment: You are using commas and spaces and also the word "at" in the examples. Does the regex need to understand all three formats? Are there other formats that could happen? Please provide an extensive explanation what the end format should look like.

Comment: When giving an example *always* show both the desired result and the erroneous result your code generated. If an exception is raised, give the error message and the line of code that generated the error. “My code is not working” is not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one is working.

```
\d+(?= ?\| ?BUY 1[, ] ?GET 1(?:,? ?| at )50%)
\d+(?= ?\| ?BUY 1[, ] ?GET 1(?:, ?| at )40%)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the spaces in between, and also dont group with brackets. As I undestand you want to capture the price. So we capture it with \d+ and check if there are needed context with a lookahead like (?= \| BUY 1 GET 1 50%)

```
\d+(?= ?\| ?BUY 1[, ] ?GET 1(?:,? ?| at )50%)
\d+(?= ?\| ?BUY 1[, ] ?GET 1(?:, ?| at )40%)
```

demo

https://regex101.com/r/vG1kzW/3

https://regex101.com/r/QImMZf/2